# EOF Exception when using input() on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, eof

I have the following function throw me EOF exception:

```
def timeTracker(veiksmai, directory, cap, ipAddress):

while not is_non_zero(str(cap)):
    pass
print("Capture started confirmed")
print(veiksmai)
print(len(veiksmai))
print('|    Time, s |   Event   |', file=open(str(directory), 'a'))
startTime = time.time()
i = 0
while i != len(veiksmai):
    print('|    ' + str(round(time.time() - startTime)) + ' |   ' + veiksmai[i] + '   |\n', file=open(str(directory), 'a'))
    input("Press enter for next")
    i += 1
```

I get exception on this line:

```
input("Press enter for next")
```

The exception is as follows:

```
File "/home/dovydas/PycharmProjects/packet-capture/main_new.py", line 29, in timeTracker
input("Press enter for next")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I am using the latest PyCharm and Python 3.6.5

I have Googled the issue but as far as I know, there should be no problems with this using PyCharm.

I have tried creating an empty variable like:

```
var1 = input("Press enter for next")
```

But that didn't help. Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:

Here is the main method:

```
ipAddress = input("Enter ip address which you want to capture: ")
capDir = input("Enter directory of capture file: ")
timeDir = input("Enter directory of timeline file: ")


actions = []
userInput = ""
while userInput != "DONE":
    userInput = input('Enter next action: ')
    if userInput != 'DONE':
        actions.append(userInput)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=capture, args=(ipAddress, capDir,))
    p.start()

    p2 = Process(target=timeTracker, args=(actions, timeDir, capDir, ipAddress,))
    p2.start()
```

Comment: can you show us how you're calling your program? the issue here is that `stdin` is closed before `input` is called, which usually comes from not having an interactive shell as `stdin`

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I have added the snippet on what happens before calling that method. p2 is the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `multiprocessing.Process` explicitly closes [`stdin` and opens `/dev/null`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms), and the standard input is where `input` reads from. You might consider using `subprocess` or `threads` instead.